# There was no endpoint listening GPService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Tags: c#, web-services

Dynamic GP 2013 Setup successfully done at server (Windows Server 2008 R2). Database auto created on SQL Server 2008 R2. Services are created and these are running.

Taking a console application on Visual Studio 2012 and added the Web Service of Dynamic GP. `http://MyDomainName:48620/Dynamics/GPService/mex`

Use a sample code to test which are given bellow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using  WebServiceConsoleApp.DynamicGPAtTen;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WebServiceConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompanyKey companyKey;
            Context context;
            Vendor vendor;
            VendorKey vendorKey;
            Policy vendorPolicy;

            // Create an instance of the service
            DynamicsGPClient wsDynamicsGP = new DynamicsGPClient();

            // Create a context object with which to call the web service
            context = new Context();

            // Specify which company to use (sample company)
            companyKey = new CompanyKey();
            companyKey.Id = (-1);

            // Set up the context
            context.OrganizationKey = companyKey;

            // Create a new vendor key
            vendorKey = new VendorKey();
            vendorKey.Id = "TstVndr0001";

            // Populate the vendor object
            vendor = new Vendor();
            vendor.Key = vendorKey;
            vendor.Name = "TestVendor0001";

            // Get the create policy for the vendor
            vendorPolicy = wsDynamicsGP.GetPolicyByOperation("CreateVendor",  context);

            // Create the vendor
            wsDynamicsGP.CreateVendor(vendor, context, vendorPolicy);

            // Close the service
            if (wsDynamicsGP.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                wsDynamicsGP.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**After running application it gives following error message:**

`There was no endpoint listening at http://MyDomainName:48620/Dynamics/GPService/GPService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.`

**Any idea to solve?**

Detail info on Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Services**

Check that the following Windows Services are running (Start > All Programs > Administrative Tools > Services):

- Microsoft Dynamics GP Service Host
- eConnect for Microsoft Dynamics GP
  2013 Integration Service

**Check Legacy version by opening the following URL in your browser:**

`http://MyDomainName:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices`

**Check Native version by opening the following URL in your browser:**

`http://MyDomainName:48620/Dynamics/GPService`

**Not working?**

If neither are working try checking all of these things: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950844

Please let us know if you hit any issues at any stage of the above...

Comment: Our version is Dynamic GP 2013. `http://MyDomainName:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices/DynamicsGPService.asmx` this works lower of 2013.

Comment: @KhalidFarhan - I have expanded to include Legacy and Native and a few tests. See what you get when you browse to each and we can go from there.

Comment: Got solution by changing config file domain name to IP `<endpoint address="http://MyIP:48620/Dynamics/GPService/GPService" ...` Facing another problem [The caller was not authenticated by the GP Service] :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477436/the-caller-was-not-authenticated-by-the-gp-service]

Comment: Good stuff! I hope my answer helped a little? Sounds like you need to look at your DNS settings.